# How can I show a show cursor or image on top of listview in qml

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I'm trying to place Rectangle items inside a listview in qml. I need to show a cursor or image which resembles cursor between two items in the listview. The cursor should be able to switch positions between spaces of different items in listview.

[image: ListView with cursor between items]

Please help me with ideas to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty and can be improved especially when taking the center of the delegate item and calculate if the mouse is closer to the left or right side of the delegate, but it shows how to show such a cursor.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 240
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: listView
        x: 40
        y: 40
        width: 400
        height: 50
        spacing: 10
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal

        model: ["Item 0", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 50
            border.width: 1

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: modelData
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onPositionChanged: function(mouse) {
                let item = listView.itemAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
                if (item)
                    cursor.x = item.x - listView.spacing
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: cursor
            width: listView.spacing
            height: listView.height
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```